# konsole command does not run at WSL Ubuntu20.04; libQt5Core.so not found

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed from the microsoft store Ubuntu 20.04, and installed the "konsole" with

```
sudo apt-get -y install konsole
```

This does not give any error messages and the "konsole" program is installed into "/usr/bin/konsole".
The version of konsole is "4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1"

when I want to run konsole, I get the error message:

```
konsole: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The libQt including libQt5Core.so.5 is indeed present in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, where libDt5Core.so.5 is a symbolic link to libQt5Core.so.5.12.8

this is the output of cat /ext/ld.so.conf.d/*

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

As far as I can see everything is identical to my parallel Ubuntu 18.04 installation, where the "konsole" command runs just fine? (Of course the version of konsole differs)
I have not yet installed a native Ubuntu 20.04 , yet I'd love to get Ubuntu 20.04 to run for my applications on Microsoft Windows WSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to follow these steps:
- Install binutils

```
apt-get install -y binutils
```

Then run:

```
strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Br

Comment: Thank you, that worked. binutils had been installed, but I would never have come up with the second command. (had to run that as sudo of course). Consider it solved.

Comment: For those interested, there is a bug open on the WSL github project for this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3023